# Using LaTeX with dysgraphia

Tags: speed

I saw that another user on here used LaTeX and mentioned having a writing disability. As I stand now I take over a minute two write out a super simple formula on paper in a way that's legible. I've seen people mention that it's a wonderful tool for doing homework with and helps with clarity and neatness which are two things I struggle with when doing mathematics, I confuse my 9's with a's and q's ect. I was wondering if I could benefit from submitting my homework using LaTeX to help speed things up to quicker than a minute per formula (that's just writing down the basic formula and then I of course have to write my steps to solve it which takes even more time). Of course I know this is stack exchange and this might be a subjective question but I was wondering what people who have been using for a long time might be able to tell me about the system and how it compares to handwriting homework.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Although I can't help, there are quite a few people here who are interested in, and working on, accessibility, so I think this is a reasonable question.

Comment: With the right editor and proper shortcuts it might be possible to write fast. With the right keyboard setup, it might be even faster to insert `α` than `\alpha` into a document (using package [`unicode-math`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432529)). Input speed will also depend on your keyboard layout. On the default QWERTZ layout, the characters ``\``, `{`, `}`, `[` and `]` are all in akward places. If it's not only about math, MarkDown might be a faster and easier approach if it's “just” homework. Math will still be in TeX input syntax but other things might be faster and easier to handle.

Comment: It is also worth saying that LaTeX has a rather steep learning curve. You will almost certainly be much slower in the beginning. People answering questions here will tell you it's worth the effort. The people who decided it wasn't worth it aren't answering questions here. I'd second the suggestion to look at MarkDown. There are also equation editors in word processors and some standalone formula editors, as well as online options. Make an account on somewhere like Overleaf and try it out. That way you can decide whether you want to invest the time and effort without having to install TeX.

Comment: Another alternative, especially considering an heavy use of maths, is LyX. For the math mode is nearly  a WYSIWYG editor where many symbols and structures can be selected with the mouse.